# Ces phrases sont elles possibles : "Les 20% de profit restés/resté ont été volés", "Les 20% de profit qui reste/restent ont été volés" ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, accord, participe-passé, subordonnées

Sur le site internet de l'Office québécois de la langue française (http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1597), il est dit que *si la fraction ou le pourcentage sont précédés d’un déterminant (les, ces, etc.), l’accord du verbe se fait obligatoirement avec l’expression du pourcentage.* Or, je me demande si dans le cas où c'est un **participe/adjectif/subordonnée relative**, pourra-t-on quand même considérer que le **participe/adjectif/subordonnée relative** qualifie le complément et non le pourcentage?

Voici un exemple donné sur ce site : ***Nous devons partager les 15 % de profit qui restent.***

Peut-on écrire :

**"Les 20% de [profit qui reste] ont été volés"** --> C'est 20% qui sont volés (accord verbe avec le pourcentage uniquement car il y a "les"), mais c'est le profit qui reste.

**"Les 20% de [profit] qui restent ont été volés"** --> C'est 20% qui sont volés (accord verbe avec le pourcentage uniquement car il y a "les"), et c'est les 20% qui restent.

Et aussi pour :

**"Les 20% de profit restés ont été volés"**

**"Les 20% de profit resté ont été volés"**  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1/** Est-ce qu'on peut écrire:
"Les 20% de [profit qui reste] ont été volés" --> C'est 20% qui sont volés (accord verbe avec le pourcentage uniquement car il y a "les"), mais c'est le profit qui reste.

*« Profit » est un nom massique donc, il force l'accord au singulier. Dans ce cas, à partir d'un certain profit P, il  restait un profit R (R<P), et maintenant  20 %  de ce reste (20 % R) sont manquants parce qu'ils ont été volés. C'est à dire qu'il ne reste que 80 % de R.*

**2/** "Les 20% de [profit] qui restent ont été volés" --> C'est 20% qui sont volés (accord verbe avec le pourcentage uniquement car il y a "les"), et c'est les 20% qui restent.

*Le sens est différent ; à partir d'un certain profit P, il restait 20 % (20 % P), et maintenant ils ont été volés ; donc il ne reste plus de profit.*

**3/** "Les 20% de profit restés ont été volés"
"Les 20% de profit resté ont été volés" ?

*On n'utilise pas « resté » mais « restant » dans ce cas (« Les 20% de profit restants ont été volés  — Les 20% de profit restant ont été volés ») ; le principe est le même.*

Comment: Hélas, (très) mauvaise lecture.

Answer (score 2):

C'est un peu confus. Essayons de clarifier les choses.

> Les 20% restant ont été volés.

<sub>Correction : La phrase ci-dessus est ambivalente. Elle est produite à cause d'un biais cognitif. En effet, lorsqu'on l'interprète littéralement elle signifie qu'il ne reste que 20% mais que la totalité a été volée.</sub>

La phrase ci-dessus est équivalente à « Les 20% du profit qui restait ont été volés ». En généralisant, c'est équivalent à « Les 20% du reste ont été volés ».

> Reste: **n.m.** Ce qui reste d'un tout dont une ou plusieurs parties ont été retranchées.

Le mot « restant » dans la première phrase mentionnée « est » un participe présent¹ (à ne pas confondre avec un adjectif). Il a le rôle de la proposition subordonnée relative « qui restait » : c'est un complément du nom (on désigne le profit dégagé avant le vol).

En appliquant les règles de grammaire mentionnées :

1. Après l’expression d’une fraction ou d’un pourcentage suivis d’un complément, l’accord du verbe **peut se faire** au singulier ou au pluriel, selon le sens ou l’importance que l’on accorde à la proportion exprimée par la fraction ou le pourcentage, ou à l’ensemble exprimé par le complément.
2. Si la fraction ou le pourcentage sont précédés d’un déterminant (les, ces, etc.), l’accord du verbe **se fait obligatoirement** avec l’expression du pourcentage.

On conjugue le participe passé au pluriel.

Remarque : on accorde le participe passé à la voix passive.

Le problème découle de l'expression qui n'est pas tout à fait correcte : il faut nécessairement employer différents temps pour bien saisir ce dont on parle.

L'autre difficulté réside dans l'expression choisie comme modèle « Nous devons partager les 15% de profit **qui restent** ». La subordonnée relative fait le lien entre deux choses signifiées : « dans ce qui reste (15% du profit) nous devons effectuer un partage ». On sous-entend une diminution : 85% du profit n'est plus inclus dans le partage.

---

<sub>¹ Au sens strict, c'est un nom.</sub>